# angular2 component refresh data

Tags: angularjs, angular, components

I have a snippet of code in my anuglar2 Component that loads the data on during the component initialization phase - I want the data to get updated during page refresh, what am I doing wrong?,

here's my snippet:

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
        this._productService.getProducts().subscribe(
            products => this.products = products,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want it to refresh periodically or do you mean a literal F5 refresh?

Comment: I want to do it with F5

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with **ngOnInit()**. It gets called once only when component is initialized. When you refresh, **ngOnInit()** will not be called again.So, you should load data in **constructor** or in some other **custom function**.

```
constructor(private _productService:productService){
   _productService.getProducts().subscribe(
                                 products => this.products = products,
                                 error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

**OR**

```
// make sure you call it from somewhere.
GetProducts()
{ 
      this._productService.getProducts().subscribe(
            products => this.products = products,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Comment: is there a better way of going about it other than sticking onReload() or getProducts() method somewhere in the template?

Comment: You want real time updates? if so, you might think of `rxjs library` but not sure how exactly.

Comment: I think there's a way to do this via routing

Comment: What would you do with routing?

Comment: tell the component to refresh

Comment: You want to hook F5 and just refresh a specific component? That seems kind of overengineered. How about a refresh button on your component which just does that.